# Mqtt disconnecting when another publish

Tags: c, linux, mqtt, yocto, paho

I have 2 gateways (OS:yocto embedded linux ).Which send and receive commands from a cloud application.When i run mqtt application in gateway 1 alone, it is able to send and receive commands from cloud application.And when i run gatway1 and gateway 2 together, they are able to send commands to cloud application but when cloud send a command to any of the gateway the other one is disconnecting.

Im using paho-mqtt c library version 3.1

i tried different client ID specific TOPIC but none of them worked,please give me some help .

here is my MQTT application.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "MQTTAsync.h"

#if !defined(WIN32)
#include <unistd.h>
#else
#include <windows.h>
#endif

#define ADDRESS     "test.mosquitto.org:1883"
#define CLIENTID    "ExampleClientPub1" //client id is UNIQUE
#define TOPIC_SUB   "pubTopic" /*2 gateways subscribed to this topic and cloud app publish to this topic */
#define TOPIC_PUB   "MQTT Examples" /*gateway send message to this topic and cloud app subscribe to this topic*/
#define PAYLOAD     "******from app2!******" /* sample payload*/
#define QOS         1
#define TIMEOUT     10000L

volatile MQTTAsync_token deliveredtoken;

int finished = 0;
MQTTAsync client;
int disc_finished = 0;
int subscribed = 0;

void connlost(void *context, char *cause)
{
    MQTTAsync_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTAsync_connectOptions_initializer;
    int rc;

    printf("\nConnection lost\n");
    printf("     cause: %s\n", cause);

    printf("Reconnecting\n");
    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
    if ((rc = MQTTAsync_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to start connect, return code %d\n", rc);
        finished = 1;
    }
}

void onDisconnect(void* context, MQTTAsync_successData* response)
{
    printf("Successful disconnection\n");
    finished = 1;
}

void onSend(void* context, MQTTAsync_successData* response)
{
//  MQTTAsync_disconnectOptions opts = MQTTAsync_disconnectOptions_initializer;
    int rc;

    printf("Message with token value %d delivery confirmed\n", response->token);

//  opts.onSuccess = onDisconnect;
//  opts.context = client;

//  if ((rc = MQTTAsync_disconnect(client, &opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
//  {
//      printf("Failed to start sendMessage, return code %d\n", rc);
//      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
//  }
}

void onConnectFailure(void* context, MQTTAsync_failureData* response)
{
    printf("Connect failed, rc %d\n", response ? response->code : 0);
    finished = 1;
}

void transfer() /*function  usesd for publishing*/
{
    static int i=1;
    printf("\n................................Transmitt %d................................\n",i++);
    MQTTAsync_responseOptions opts = MQTTAsync_responseOptions_initializer;
    MQTTAsync_message pubmsg = MQTTAsync_message_initializer;
    int rc;

    printf("Successful connection\n");

    opts.onSuccess = onSend;
    opts.context = client;

    pubmsg.payload = PAYLOAD;
    pubmsg.payloadlen = strlen(PAYLOAD);
    pubmsg.qos = QOS;
    pubmsg.retained = 0;
    deliveredtoken = 0;

    if ((rc = MQTTAsync_sendMessage(client, TOPIC_PUB, &pubmsg, &opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to start sendMessage, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

/************subscribe****************/

void onSubscribe(void* context, MQTTAsync_successData* response)
{
    printf("Subscribe succeeded\n");
    subscribed = 1;
}

void onSubscribeFailure(void* context, MQTTAsync_failureData* response)
{
    printf("Subscribe failed, rc %d\n", response ? response->code : 0);
    finished = 1;
}

void onConnect(void* context, MQTTAsync_successData* response)
{
    MQTTAsync client = (MQTTAsync)context;
    MQTTAsync_responseOptions opts = MQTTAsync_responseOptions_initializer;
    MQTTAsync_message pubmsg = MQTTAsync_message_initializer;
    int rc;

    printf("Successful connection\n");

    printf("Subscribing to topic %s\nfor client %s using QoS%d\n\n"
           "Press Q<Enter> to quit\n\n", TOPIC_SUB, CLIENTID, QOS);
    opts.onSuccess = onSubscribe;
    opts.onFailure = onSubscribeFailure;
    opts.context = client;

    deliveredtoken = 0;

    if ((rc = MQTTAsync_subscribe(client, TOPIC_SUB, QOS, &opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to start subscribe, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int msgarrvd(void *context, char *topicName, int topicLen, MQTTAsync_message *message)
{
    int i;
    char* payloadptr;

    printf("Message arrived\n");
    printf("     topic: %s\n", topicName);
    printf("   message: ");

    payloadptr = message->payload;
    for(i=0; i<message->payloadlen; i++)
    {
        putchar(*payloadptr++);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    MQTTAsync_freeMessage(&message);
    MQTTAsync_free(topicName);
    return 1;
}

int main ()
{
    MQTTAsync_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTAsync_connectOptions_initializer;
    MQTTAsync_message pubmsg = MQTTAsync_message_initializer;
    MQTTAsync_token token;
    int rc;

    MQTTAsync_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID, MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
    MQTTAsync_setCallbacks(client, NULL, connlost, msgarrvd, NULL);

    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
    conn_opts.onSuccess = onConnect;
    conn_opts.onFailure = onConnectFailure;
    conn_opts.context = client;

    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
    conn_opts.onSuccess = onConnect;
    conn_opts.onFailure = onConnectFailure;
    conn_opts.context = client;
    if ((rc = MQTTAsync_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to start connect, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(!subscribed)
        #if defined(WIN32)
            Sleep(100);
        #else
            usleep(10000L);
        #endif

    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
        transfer();
        sleep(2);
    }


}
```

Comment: Edit the question to show your code

Comment: questn edtd.the above code is compiled separate gateway1 and gateway2 and cloud application with necessary changes in CLIENTID and TOPICs . @hardillb

Comment: If you run the clients against your own broker is there anything in the broker logs as to why it disconnects?

Comment: I will check  that..but this application  is works  fine with x86 machine and fails on target  device

Comment: Where are you getting this libraries? Refer to: http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTClient/html/pubasync.html to a c asynchronous publication example. Maybe it is worth trying the lates t version?

Comment: fixed. it was a MAC address  conflict